# Is あたし seen as soft?

Tags: nuances, feminine-speech

Is あたし seen as soft and girly like the particle わ is? Or can a girl just say it and not sound emotional or dramatic or soft?

Comment: You can think of it as simply a more colloquial version of わたし for women only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, あたし is a very feminine form of わたし.

<strike>However, あたし isn't really often used outside of anime and idol usage, as it gives a very unrealistic "cutesy" kind of vibe. (at least in my experience)</strike>

<strike>Of course I'm sure it's used appropriately somewhere, but it's best to stick to わたし/わたくし for everyday usage.</strike>

EDIT:あたし can be used in real life applications as a softer/feminine わたし (thanks to  broccoli forest)

Comment: No, あたし is very often in actual world, after all it's a lighter pronunciation of わたし.

Comment: Should note that as far as anime usage goes, there exists an 「あたし」 that sounds very tough, like a female leader of a gang. That's often slurred together with 「は」, like 「あたしゃ容赦はしないよ」. In the end, it's how you pronounce it.